# C - My value from my pointer change by itself

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I wanted to make a double array where the size will depends of the value enter by the user but when my double array is around [1999] I got segmentation fault.

So I decided to use pointers but here the problem, I set my value at 0 but after a few loop iterations, my value would change by itself.

Here is my code:

```
int Limit = 0;
int Bomb = 0;  

int getsum(int num)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (num)
    {
        result = result + num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int calc_limit(int x)
{
    while ((getsum(x)) < Bomb)
        x++;

    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Bomb = atoi(argv[1]);
    Limit = calc_limit(0);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    bool **visited;                                                                                     

    if ((visited = malloc(Limit * sizeof(bool))) == NULL)
        return;
    while (i < Limit)
    {
        if ((visited[i] = malloc(Limit)) == NULL)
            return;
        while (j < Limit)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    //  printf("%d\n", visited[0][0]);                                                                                 
}
```

So for example, visited[0][0], is equal 0 when I set it but suddenly it will became equal 176.

I checked when this value change, and it change it change in my second loop when i = 3.

I have no idea why.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please check out how to use `for` loops

Comment: Your code does not compile and please format your code correctly. Please post real code

Comment: I know how to use `for` loops, i'm just used to use `while` loops.

Comment: @MichaelWalz my code should compile now, I added the function I missed

Comment: How do you invoke the program? What is supposed to be in `atoi(argv[1]);`?

Comment: Wow, I missed so many things in my question, I'm sorry guys.
Argv[1] is supposed to be a number betwen 10 and 30

Comment: Another score for the `visited = malloc(Limit * sizeof(*visited))` coding style camp.

Comment: @Lundin yes this is the right ansser, thank you !

Comment: @Thebeginner As a side note, allocating data like this with multiple calls to malloc does _not_ give you a 2D array, but something else. In this case you should have used a 2D array instead. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the documentation, it was interesting and I implemented it in my code.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour for calling `malloc` without a declaration in scope. You should do `#include <stdlib.h>` and also `#include <stdbool.h>` at the top

Comment: They are in, without the include I can't compile. I just forget to add them on this part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you don't allocate enough memory for `visited`.

```
if ((visited = malloc(Limit * sizeof(bool))) == NULL)
```

should be:

```
if ((visited = malloc(Limit * sizeof (bool*))) == NULL)
```

or:

```
if ((visited = malloc(Limit * sizeof *visited)) == NULL)
```

Note that `sizeof` is an operator and not a function. Therefore most code styleguides recommend a space between `sizeof` and its parameter.

Comment: That was the reason, thanks.
I'm curious why it did this exactly

Comment: @Thebeginner Compare the value you get for `sizeof (bool)` with `sizeof (bool*)`. You will see that the former is smaller than the latter on your platform. My guess is that you get the values `1` and `8` or perhaps `1` and `4`.

Comment: Also `visited[i] = malloc(Limit)` should be `visited[i] = malloc(Limit * sizeof *visited[i])`